# Write file to a PNP device connected to a Windows PC

Tags: c#, windows, mobile-devices, plug-and-play

By plugging in a PNP device to a Windows PC I want to know if the device supports a feature of data transferring. I am majoraly interested in pushing some content to device.
So, for example when I am plugging in a Windows Phone I can see over windows managment query that 5 new devices are added

> Name: Windows Phone
>
> CompartibleId: USB\MS_COMP_MTP,
>   USB\Class_06&SubClass_01&Prot_01, USB\Class_06&SubClass_01,
>   USB\Class_06
>
> ---
>
> Name: WinUsb Device
>
> CompartibleId: USB\MS_COMP_WINUSB,
>   USB\Class_ff&SubClass_ff&Prot_ff, USB\Class_ff&SubClass_ff,
>   USB\Class_ff
>
> ---
>
> Name: WinUsb Device
>
> CompartibleId: USB\MS_COMP_WINUSB,
>   USB\Class_ff&SubClass_ff&Prot_ff, USB\Class_ff&SubClass_ff,
>   USB\Class_ff
>
> ---
>
> Name: WinUsb Device
>
> CompartibleId: USB\MS_COMP_WINUSB,
>   USB\Class_ff&SubClass_ff&Prot_ff, USB\Class_ff&SubClass_ff,
>   USB\Class_ff
>
> ---
>
> Name: USB Composite Device
>
> CompartibleId:
>   USB\DevClass_00&SubClass_00&Prot_00, USB\DevClass_00&SubClass_00,
>   USB\DevClass_00, USB\COMPOSITE

How can I now get a glue that:

- All the devices are parts of a single device
- The device allows me to save a file on it
- Find an indicator that certainly tells me about the suppoted file transfer protocol
- In case if there are more than a sigle possiblility for file trasfer select the more fastest(or modern)

I will appreaciate any help even if you could just tell me a focused direction where I should continue my study/investigation.

I am looking at a generic way to work with devices. Desired implementation language is C#.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly You can consult this [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/602568/Windows-Device-Drivers) it gives you details of Windows Device Drivers.
[SharpUSBLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpUSBLib/) and [HidLibrary](https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary) are two widely used libraries you can even get a tutorial project with implementation [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/).
SharpUsbLib earlier version used to screw up systems.
 
Would prefer [libusbdotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/).
If you have to work with an USB device (send requests, process responses), this library was the best solution I could find.

Pros:

Has all methods you need to work in synch or asynch mode.
Source code provided
Enough samples to start using it straight away.
Cons:

Poor documentation (it's common problem for open source projects). Basically, you can find just common description of methods in the CHM help file and that's it. But I still find provided samples and source code is enough for coding. Just sometimes I see a strange behaviour and want to know why it was implemented in this way and can't get even a hint...
Seems unsupported any more. Last version was issued in Oct 2010. And it's hard to get answers sometimes.